# Showing an infinite intersection of sets has a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are sets where each $A_n$ has a supremum and $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n \neq \emptyset$, then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ has a supremum.

I am about 49% sure what the answer is, thinking of the Nested interval theorem, I have strong suspicions this statement is true.

The only thing which irks me is that since we have an infinite intersection of sets, then for any $x_n \in A_n $ won't there always be an $x_{n+1} \in A_{n+1}$ such that we can't find a least upper bound? Of course according to the nested interval property this isn't true, but the nested interval theorem makes use of some arbitrary interval and nested sequence. In this case, we do not have an interval, just an arbitrary set.

In any case, I tried a proof by contradiction which I am not confident in the robustness of, but here it is:

Assume $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ does not have a supremum.

This implies that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is either unbounded above, or empty or both.

However, we are given that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is non-empty.

So assume $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is unbounded above.

This implies that there exists some $A_{n_k}$ which is unbounded above, however we are given that each $A_n$ is bounded above.

Hence the supremum of $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ must exist.

I would very much appreciate any help. Would a proof by induction be more suitable here? Or perhaps a straightforward proof?

Comment: The proof is correct, though it could be stated better. In fact *all* of the sets $A_n$ are bounded above, and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ is a subset of each of them, so it must be either empty or bounded above. Since the former has been excluded by hypothesis, it must be bounded above.

Comment: You’re welcome.